# Express server not running when using ng serve

Tags: mean-stack, mean

My server.js is not getting executed when I use ng serve command from angular-cli. When I use node server, it works fine.

server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const api = require('./server/routes/api');

const port = 3000;

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/Colab')));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.get('/api', api);

app.get('*', (req,res)=>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/Colab/index.html'));
});

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, ()=>console.log(`Server is running on localhost:${port}`));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following commands:

```
  npm start
```

OR

```
  node app.js
```

Comment: I can use node server.js but when I make changes, I'll have to rebuild the app and re-run the server. I want to avoid that. Is nodemon a better alternative for this?

Comment: yep, sure Ashish, thats what nodemon is built for. I always use nodemon whenever I'm working with node.